# user cannot add key to hashmap in java while loop

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, java.util.scanner

I am training myself in the use of hashmaps and thought it would be a good idea to build myself a financial planner program. I am trying to prompt user for a string key (bill name) and then apply that to a double value (also input by the user) which equates to the value of the bill. The result will be a hashmap with bill names (such as internet or electricity, for eg) and the values that those bills come to.

I have built a class called InputData - as follows:

```
package financial.planner;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputData {
    private double salary;
    private Map<String, Double> bills;
    private boolean chooseContinue;

public InputData(){
    super();
    this.salary = 0.0;
    this.bills = new HashMap<>();
    this.chooseContinue = false;
}
//getters and setters for salary
public double getSalary(){
    return this.salary;
}
public void setSalary(double aSalary){
    this.salary = aSalary;
}
//getters and setters for bills
public Map<String, Double> getBills(){
    return this.bills;
}
public void setBills(Map<String, Double> aBills){
    this.bills = aBills;
}
//getters and setters for chooseContinue
public boolean getChooseContinue(){
    return this.chooseContinue;
}
public void setChooseContinue(boolean aChooseContinue){
    this.chooseContinue = aChooseContinue;
}
public void FPSalary(){
    Scanner scanVar = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter salary: \n");
    this.setSalary(scanVar.nextDouble());
}
public void FPBills(){
    Scanner scanVar = new Scanner(System.in);
    Map<String, Double> billsMap = new HashMap<>();
    while(!this.getChooseContinue())
    {
        System.out.println("Enter bill name: \n");
        String billName = scanVar.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter bill value: \n");
        double billValue = scanVar.nextDouble();
        billsMap.put(billName, billValue);
        this.FPChooseContinue();
    }
    this.setBills(billsMap);
    setChooseContinue(false);
}
public void FPChooseContinue(){
    Scanner scanVar = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Any more to add (y or n)?\n");
    String yesOrNo = scanVar.nextLine();
    switch (yesOrNo) {
        case "y":
            break;
        case "n":
            this.setChooseContinue(true);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.print("Please enter y or n");
    }
}

}
```

And in my main:

```
package financial.planner;

public class FinancialPlanner 
{    

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    InputData IDobject = new InputData();

    System.out.println("Financial Planner 1.0");

    IDobject.FPSalary();
    IDobject.FPBills();
    System.out.println(IDobject.getBills());

}
```

}

The Program runs according to plan unless I try to add a second key (ie bill name) - it ignores this request and runs straight to the bill value instead:

> Financial Planner 1.0 Enter salary:  30000 Enter bill name:
>
> gas Enter bill value:
>
> 450 Any more to add (y or n)?
>
> y Enter bill name:
>
> Enter bill value:
>
> 37 Any more to add (y or n)?
>
> n {=37.0, gas=450.0}

I'd very much appreciate an experienced programmer to lend me a hand on this one - Im probably doing something pretty dumb - but I love programming and want to get better! please help! Any other advice about my code would be also greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do by calling super(); in InputData's constructor?

Comment: I am perhaps planning on using the class as a subclass at some point and put it in - is this bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, `nextLine()` does the following:

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end.

A stray newline character must be causing the `String billName = scanVar.nextLine ();` to skip a line, since it's theoretically a line to be read.

You can use `next()` instead, which reads until the next input delimiter.

Comment: many thanks broncoAbierto - I really should be reading the docs myself so sorry about that. Anyhow this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this you have interchanged the yes and no blocks

public void FPChooseContinue(){
        Scanner scanVar = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Any more to add (y or n)?\n");
        String yesOrNo = scanVar.nextLine();
        switch (yesOrNo) {
            case "y":
             this.setChooseContinue(true);
                break;
            case "n":
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("Please enter y or n");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The nextDouble() method leaves the '\n' symbol which gets picked up immediately by nextLine(), skipping over the next input thus throwing an exception. What you want to do is use nextLine() for everything, and parse it later. So just replace

```
double billValue = scanVar.nextDouble();
```

WITH

```
double billValue = Double.parseDouble(scanVar.nextLine());
```